# Quantum probability vs. Kolmogorov's probability

Tags: probability-theory, quantum-mechanics

It has been argued that quantum probability requires a different treatment from other random events, and a different formalization is needed than that provided by Kolmogorov's axioms. And as a physicist by training I have read such statements dozens of times.

However, I have never seen *a simple and concrete example* showing that some result of quantum mechanics cannot be reduced to the usal treatment random events over a measure space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$.

**Could someone provide a reasonable example of the probability used in quantum mechanics not being reducible to Kolmogorov's axioms?**

---

*Disclaimer*: I am asking the question here and not in a physics space, because I would like to see a rigorous demonstration of the fact, with the formality and rigor proper to mathematics, so as not to leave room for the ambiguity typical of discussions in physics.

Comment: I'm not sure about the statements you have seen, and I have never seen the term in your title you are asking about. I very much fear you are asking about a quantum-mechanical [quasiprobability distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiprobability_distribution), ubiquitous in physics, where  different phase-space points (x,p) and (x',p') violate Kolmogorov's third axiom, as they are not mutually exclusive alternatives, by the uncertainty principle; in addition such quasi probabilities are not semi-positive definite. Is this what you are asking about?

Comment: I recall a similar thing about "subjective probabilities" by Jeffrey and some statisticians. I recall giving this criticism as well: if you propose new probability models that are different from Kolmogorov's, you will lose one of the three axioms (positivity, sigma additivity and standarisation), and obviously you want to keep positivity and standarisation, so you necessarily must lose sigma additivity. But then, the probability of disjoint events do not necessarily add up, so probability is either lost or created in the vacuum, a completely shocking result...

Comment: I think in part no one takes this approach very seriously except for a few die-hard philosophers who find standard probability so counterintuitive that, therefore they think, must be wrong and another approach should be more reasonable.

Answer (score 3):

A simple counterexample is given in a 9-page talk note [1]. It shows that for a certain $8$-dimensional Hilbert space, there is no embedding to any classical probability space.

More concretely, assuming the converse, i.e. there is a measurable space $M = (\Omega, \mathcal{F})$, an embedding (a map that sends each quantum observable to a classical random variable, and a map that sends each quantum (pure) state to a probability measure on $M$), such that

1. The induced probability distribution is compatible (condition KS1 in [1]).
2. The associated random variables are assigned in a compatible way that respects any measurable re-scaling (condition KS2 in [1]).

Note: The proof only use a very small subset KS2' of KS2, roughly saying that if $A$ and $B$ are your (quantum) observable, and if $f_A$ and $f_B$ are the corresponding (classical) measurable functions, then $f_{AB}$ = $f_A f_B$. More stringently, the proof only uses for the case where $AB = BA$, **so non-commutativity isn't an issue here**.

Then cleverly construct a state $\Psi$ [1, (18)] and an observable $O = A_1 A_2 A_3$ [1, (15)(17)]. Its expected value is $\langle O\rangle_\Psi = -1$ [1, (24)]. However, you can show that if such an embedding exists, mapping $O$ to $a_1 a_2 a_3$, then $a_1 a_2 a_3$ takes value $1$ almost everywhere [1, (22)], a contradiction.

#### Discussions

1. **Locality assumption of any sort is not required here.**
2. Note that [1] claims to prove this for all Hilbert spaces with dimension at least $3$, but as far as I can tell, the proof only show for a $8$ dimensional one.
3. More details from the paper: If you dig hard into it, the contradiction still comes from noncommutativity. In the clever setup, three observables $Q_1=A_1B_2B_3, Q_2=B_1A_2B_3, Q_3=B_1B_2A_3$ are given. While they are commuting, their sub-components (the $A$'s and $B$'s) are not. And while
   $$1 = \langle Q_1Q_2Q_3 \rangle_\Psi = \langle (A_1 B_2B_3)(B_1A_2B_3)(B_1B_2A_3) \rangle_\Psi$$$$ = \langle A_1 (B_2A_2B_2) A_3 \rangle_\Psi = \langle A_1 (-A_2) A_3 \rangle_\Psi = \langle (-1) A_1 A_2 A_3 \rangle_\Psi,$$
   with the nonexistent classical map $Q_1Q_2Q_3 = A_1 (B_2A_2B_2) A_3$ is mapped to $$q_1q_2q_3 = (b_1^2)(b_2^2)(b_3^2) a_1 a_2 a_3  = (+1) a_1a_2a_3.$$ A contradiction thus arises from the sign difference.

#### Reference

- [1] [A Simple Proof of the Kochen-Specker Theorem on the Problem of Hidden Variables](https://arxiv.org/abs/0801.4931)